# Launchpad builderror - Can't locate Debian/Debhelper/Sequence/python3.pm

Tags: dependencies, ppa, packaging, launchpad

I am getting the following error while trying to package a source file using a Launchpad recipe. However, I can successfully build the package in my machine (running 18.04)

```
dh: error: unable to load addon python3: Can't locate Debian/Debhelper/Sequence/python3.pm
```

Here is the full [buildlog](https://launchpadlibrarian.net/490819262/buildlog.txt.gz), and my `debian/control` file is as follows.

```bsh
Source: up-clock
Section: python
Priority: extra
Build-Depends: debhelper (>= 10),
 python3,
 python3-distutils-extra
Maintainer: Archisman Panigrahi <apandada1@gmail.com>
Standards-Version: 4.1.4
X-Python-Version: >= 3.5

Package: up-clock
Architecture: all
Depends: ${misc:Depends},
 ${python3:Depends},
 gir1.2-glib-2.0,
 gir1.2-gtk-3.0,
 gir1.2-webkit2-4.0
Description: A beautiful Clock, inspired by Ubuntu Touch homescreen, already on your desktop.
 Inspired by Ubuntu Touch homescreen, this clock is able to show you the
 time in a way you never seen before. The "clouds" changes colors and
 sizes automaticaly awhile showing you the time.
```

How to fix this? I have already added `python3-distutils-extra` to `Build-Depends`.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Add `dh-python` to Build-Depends in the `debian/control` file.

After doing this, Launchpad builds without throwing any error.

Answer (score 0):

Fixed the problem running:

```
apt install dh-python
```